# Are ERB and require_relative compatible?

Tags: ruby, erb, require, templating-engine

Are ERB and require_relative compatible?

I got this message

```
<internal:prelude>:31:in `require_relative': require_relative is called in erb (LoadError)
```

What does it mean?

Comment: are you using ruby 1.9x?

Answer (score 1):

The method `require_relative` only appears in Ruby 1.9.2 or later, as indicated by the greyed-out squares at [APIdock](http://apidock.com/ruby/Kernel/require_relative).